# How can you create a .aws folder?

Tags: windows-10

It says specifically in this AWS readme documentation to make a .aws folder, and other folders of this type exist (.ext), but windows says "you must type a file name" in order to try and create a folder like this and won't let you.

I could be reading this wrong, so correct me if I am.  The \ is confusing and I am used to seeing this in commenting code, but not in actual file folders.

```
You need to set up your AWS security credentials before the sample code is able
to connect to AWS. You can do this by creating a file named "credentials" at ~/.aws/ 
(C:\Users\USER_NAME\\.aws\ for Windows users) and saving the following lines in the file:

[default]
aws_access_key_id = <your access key id>
aws_secret_access_key = <your secret key>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Normal DOT before a file denotes hidden file or folder(in Linux and OSX).

If you wanted to create a folder name with DOT a front like ".aws" then while naming the folder use a dot at the end too "**.aws.**". windows will automatically remove the dot at the end and keep the folder name as ".aws"